# ampersand symbol in ajax query being ignored

Tags: javascript, ajax, url

i've isolated the problem to my ajax not allowing ampersand symbols to be inserted into the query. So for example the str or string being inputted is Fish & Chips. Only Fish Shows.

```
function showBrand(str) {
var xmlhttp;
if (str=="") {
  document.getElementById("txtBrand").innerHTML="";
  return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("txtBrand").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getBrand.php?q="+str,true); // <-- Problem?
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

When the Query gets sent to getBrand.php, and when you enter a & symbol it converts it into a variable in the url im assuming. Being terrible at ajax i don't how to fix this problem.. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getBrand.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str),true);
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` is used for separating multiple parameters in a query string. You need to use `encodeURIComponent` to ensure that all special characters in the parameter are encoded.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getBrand.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str),true);
```

Comment: only because he posted it first, you guys have the same code, thanks brother.